# Can I avoid or optimize this dynamic invocation?

Tags: c#, generics, optimization, dynamic

I'm trying to write a class which can handle many different types of inputs, all of which implement the same interface.

I have the following code:

```
private IEnumerable<IPlan> DevisePlans(ITile tile, IEnumerable<ISpace> spaces)
{
    MethodInfo method = GetType().GetMethod("DevisePlans",
                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                            null,
                                            new[] {tile.GetType(), typeof(ISpace)},
                                            null);
    var type = typeof(Func<,,>).MakeGenericType(tile.GetType(), typeof(ISpace), typeof(IEnumerable<IPlan>));
    var planner = Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, this, method);
    return spaces.SelectMany(s => (IEnumerable<IPlan>)planner.DynamicInvoke(tile, s));
}
```

There are lots of various implementations of `DevisePlans` within the class, each with a first parameter type that implements `ITile`.

```
private IEnumerable<IPlan> DevisePlans(Foo tile, ISpace space) { /* ... */ }
private IEnumerable<IPlan> DevisePlans(Bar tile, ISpace space) { /* ... */ }
```

This works, but I'm calling `DynamicInvoke` for every single iteration of my enumerable. Even if I can't completely avoid the dynamic call, is there any way to optimize this method so that the dynamic invocation no longer resides within my loop?

Comment: Can I be clear: what is this calling? are there *lots* of `DevisePlans` overloads for more specific types? or...?

Comment: Your goal with the code is a bit obscure to say the least. Could you give a high level overview? Perhaps there is another way to *skin the cat* (so to speak).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **looks** like you are using this to call the most specific **overload** (not override) of `DevisePlans` for the `tile` provided. Assuming my understanding is correct (please do tell me if I'm wrong), then just use `dynamic` - it has an inbuilt cache and is optimized for this:

```
return spaces.SelectMany(s =>
    (IEnumerable<IPlan>)DevisePlans((dynamic)tile, (dynamic)s)
);
```

and... *that's it*!

I would, however, be tempted to look for an answer involving either polymorphism (against `ITile`) or C# 4.0 variance.

Comment: This works perfectly and is so much cleaner! I'll need to test the speed of it. Where would I look for a solution using C# 4.0 variance?

Comment: @Dan with the question update/clarification I don't think the variance approach works, sorry

Comment: Why do you use `(dynamic)s`? My code compiles without it - is it just to make `ISpace` use the most specific overload as well? Also, specifying the type parameters in `SelectMany` avoids the cast to `IEnumerable<IPlan>`.

Comment: @Dan to be honest, it isn't going to matter. `dynamic` is infectious - if **part** of the call is `dynamic` (i.e. one parameter), then *they all are*. If you want to remove it for clarity, fine.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be correct. The call acts differently depending on if `(dynamic)s` is present. (If, that is, you have any overloaded functions which rely on its specific type.)

Answer (score 0):

Create an expression tree (start with Expression.Call), compile it, and you'll have a fast delegate. You should cache the delegate based on the type so that you don't compile for the same type multiple times.

Comment: You can't do that unless it is typed; if it was typed, `Delegate.CreateDelegate` (in the answer) is already more direct and faster.

Comment: You could compile an ET which takes an object parameter and casts to the correct type inside. Casting is still better than reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Think what you're looking for here is the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Define an ITileVisitor interface with your overload for each type and then ITile has a Visit method which takes the visitor as a parameter. Its the implementation of Visit which will cause the correct Devise overload to be called.

Comment: The visitor pattern requires me to modify the classes implementing `ITile`, which unfortunately I cannot do. Otherwise something like this is how I would have done it.